# Google API Oauth 2 with Installed App

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0

I am using Google API OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications & php. This is a WordPress plugin we are updating, and it was recommended to us by Google support to use Installed App instead of Web App "because you will then have a single Project ID, your users won't need to create their own using the APIs Console"

I am wrestling a bit to get the proper setup for this - Web App samples were easy enough, but I cannot find a single example of the code setup for creating these:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#formingtheurl

It says I should use "code" & "grant_type", but I don't see any functions in the apiClient to set these.

As I'm prolly not being very clear, what I'm looking for is the equivalent of this:

```
$client->setClientId();
$client->setClientSecret();
$client->setRedirectUri();
$client->setDeveloperKey();
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));
```

For Installed Apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Drive SDK documentation includes a step-by-step quickstart sample that uses OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart

This is the code you are looking for:

```
$client->setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't end up being very helpful (unless I'm just missing something small)

That code uses a completely different library set - I am using apiClient, it uses Google_Client. Has this been updated & not updated in the instruction documents?

apiClient's ->authenticate() doesn't accept a parameter, and I still don't find where to pass the first auth code.

I'll try it with the new set of libraries, but since you are from Google, could you give some insight on this confusion?

Thanks!

Comment: The PHP client library has been recently updated, the quickstart sample I'm referring to uses the latest version of the library

Comment: Thank you, Claudio! I'll use that one.

You may want to bring to the attention of the docs people that the https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#formingtheurl page is still referring people to the old library, which will cause my issue (for us clueless people, anyway)

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the link to the old library in that page. The only link I see is to the PHP library wiki page and that seems correct.

Comment: The link on this page - "Google APIs Client Library for PHP" - takes me to https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2, which is all apiClient

https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/tutorials/hello-analytics-api links you to https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ , which instructs to download apiClient

As a matter of fact, your link to a completely different area of the docs is the only mention I find of the change to Google_Client lib.

Comment: I ran into the same problem as @jmadsen - if you use the `svn checkout` command provided in the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart#install_the_google_client_library), you're guaranteed to get the latest version including Google_Client.